# How i do convert datetime to date pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have this: `2017-01-09 23:14:06+00:00`
I want this: `09/01/2017`

How can i do it  in a column (date_of_birth) of DataFrame in in Python?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['alice','bob','charlie'],
    'date_of_birth': ['2017-01-04 17:52:30+00:00','2017-01-04 17:52:35+00:00','2017-01-04 17:53:03+00:00    ']
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the datetime column with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and use [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['date_of_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_of_birth).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

---

```
print(df)

     name   date_of_birth
0    alice    04/01/2017
1      bob    04/01/2017
2  charlie    04/01/2017
```

Comment: Wow!! You helped me! Thanks